# How to return multiple functions dynamically Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I apologize if I didn't ask my question in the correct way. Let me explain my problem.

I'm working on a search function in a table, I'm adding the option to search in specific columns.

Right now I'm manually checking if the checkboxes are selected or not, then return the proper search function.

However I want to make it dynamically, I don't want to edit this code after every time I add new columns to the table. That's where I'm struggling.

This is my current code:

```
        vm.$watch('searchTerm', function (searchTerm) {
            if (!searchTerm) {
                vm.filteredTable = angular.copy(vm.table);
            } else {
                searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
                return vm.filteredTable.rows = vm.table.rows.filter(function (row) {
                    if (vm.searchFilter[0] === true ){
                        return (contains(row[vm.table.columns[0].value], searchTerm))
                    }
                    if (vm.searchFilter[1] === true ){
                        return (contains(row[vm.table.columns[1].value], searchTerm))
                    }
                    if (vm.searchFilter[2] === true ){
                        return (contains(row[vm.table.columns[2].value], searchTerm))
                    }
                    if (vm.searchFilter[3] === true ){
                        return (contains(row[vm.table.columns[3].value], searchTerm))
                    }
                    if (vm.searchFilter[4] === true ){
                        return (contains(row[vm.table.columns[4].value], searchTerm))
                    }
                    if (vm.searchFilter[5] === true ){
                        return (contains(row[vm.table.columns[5].value], searchTerm))
                    }
                    if (vm.searchFilter[6] === true ){
                        return (contains(row[vm.table.columns[6].value], searchTerm))
                    }
                    if (vm.searchFilter[7] === true ){
                        return (contains(row[vm.table.columns[7].value], searchTerm))
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

This is the way I created it, I tried to use a loop, but I can't return the functions if there is a loop. Also adding return before the for loop wont help either.

```
        vm.$watch('searchTerm', function (searchTerm) {
            if (!searchTerm) {
                vm.filteredTable = angular.copy(vm.table);
            } else {
                searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
                return vm.filteredTable.rows = vm.table.rows.filter(function (row) {
                    for (let i=0; i<vm.searchFilter.length; i++){
                        if (vm.searchFilter[i] === true ){
                            return (contains(row[vm.table.columns[i].value], searchTerm))
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

This is probably a very easy case for the most of you, so I apologize if I'm just being stupid right now. I'm working since 2 hours on this till now...

EDIT:
The function I mean:

```
        const contains = (value, searchTerm) => {
            if (!value) return false;
            return value.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm);
        }
```

2nd EDIT:
I just realized after a kind member told me that, that the first version isnt working either the way I want it.

There is the option to have a multiple selection, so if I select the first two checkboxes, then it should search in BOTH of them and not only one.

Comment: _"but I can't return the functions if there is a loop"_ - What functions?

Comment: the function "contains(a,b)"

Comment: The first version tests only the first checked checkbox. And that's what the second version does. So what's the problem?

Comment: Thank you, I just noticed that now... so the first version doesn't work either.

Comment: @Andreas maybe my last edit will explain more what my goal is

Comment: _" then it should search in BOTH of them and not only one"_ - Is it _option1_ AND _option2_ or is it _option1_ OR _option2_?

Comment: @Andreas option1 OR option2

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over the whole thing like this:

```js
vm.$watch('searchTerm', function (searchTerm) {
  if (!searchTerm) {
    vm.filteredTable = angular.copy(vm.table);
  } else {
    searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
    return vm.filteredTable.rows = vm.table.rows.filter(row => 
           vm.searchFilter.some((filter, index) => filter && contains(row[vm.table.columns[index].value])))
  }
```

By using `Array.prototype.some` you essentially ask whether your row matches at least one of the filters.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I'm trying to enable following functionality:
The user selects one OR more options. Then the search function should search if the searchterm is included in column1 OR column2

Comment: It's `const contains = (value, searchTerm) => { ... }`

Comment: You can just add it to your filters' predicate as one of the constraints, however this is the general pattern you need.

If you want, you can make an example in codesandbox.io and I'll happily show you how it works with this solution.

Comment: _"however this is the general pattern you need"_ - Which still doesn't work because the call for `contains()` is incomplete.